# Input data from excel to Web page(URL), and take a screen shot of the web page and copy results from web page to excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

[image]

Hi Team, i want to input data from excel to Web page(URL), and take a screen shot of the web page and copy results from web page to excel.

the url links - https://www.random.org/integers/

i want to generate 15 requests of random numbers from the above link. Every time i need to input value between in the for fields. When i press Get numbers i will get the random numbers. I want to copy random result numbers to my excel and also i need screen shots of both the web page as proof.

can some pls help my request.

Comment: Every time i need to input values from my excel to the four fields in the web page.

Comment: I think either automating it with python, or some macro tool like autohotkey would be much easier than excel.  I could do it in autohotkey in about 5 minutes. Otherwise, using their API would probably be a better place to start

Comment: If there is a need of screenshot, using GET request is not an option, as it will only provide a string response. With VBA only using browser, either default IE automation or any browser through Selenium will give this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it using [selenium basic wrapper](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) for vba. Props to @FlorentB for this wrapper.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GatherScreenShots()

    Dim variablesArray(), numRequests As Long, d As New ChromeDriver, i As Long, inputFields As WebElements
    Const OUTPUTPATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\screenshot"
    variablesArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    numRequests = UBound(variablesArray, 1)

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get "https://www.random.org/integers/"

        For i = 2 To numRequests '<== Note UBound was 16 but looping from 2 so 15 requests in example given
            Set inputFields = d.FindElementsByCss("input[type=""text""]")
            inputFields(2).Clear
            inputFields(2).SendKeys variablesArray(i, 2) 'NUM_INTEGERS
            inputFields(3).Clear
            inputFields(3).SendKeys variablesArray(i, 3) 'MIN_VALUE '<==Remember to check this is lower than MAX_VALUE
            inputFields(4).Clear
            inputFields(4).SendKeys variablesArray(i, 4) 'MAX_VALUE
            inputFields(5).Clear
            inputFields(5).SendKeys variablesArray(i, 5) 'NUM_COLUMNS
            d.FindElementByCss("input[value=""Get Numbers""]").Click

           ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) '<== Not needed in testing but just in case you want to add a wait

            .TakeScreenshot.SaveAs OUTPUTPATH & i - 1 & ".jpg"
            d.FindElementByCss("input[value=""Go Back""]").Click

           ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        Next i
    End With
    d.Quit
End Sub
```

**Example input data in Sheet1:**

[image: DATA]

**Note:**

There is a method `driver.TakeScreenshot().ToExcel` I believe though I prefered to output to desktop.